# Find the equation for the line that satisfies the following:

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

1. being parallel to the plane $P:x+2y-3z=1$
2. intersects orthogonally with the line $k:(x,y,z)=(1+2t,t,-1)$,$t\in R$.
3. intersects with the x-axis in any point.

I must be missing out on some information, because I end up with two unknowns when there should be none according to the correct answer.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That makes $v=(1,-2,-1)$ not (1,-3,-1). Neat use of the cross product. I'm going for the rest of the line now. Let's see how far I get.

Comment: Whoops. $\frac{1}{3}(3,-6,-3)=(1,-2,-1)$.

Comment: Yes, I got it now. The cross product gave sweet intuition. I got $λ$ through the equation $k=l$, where $l$ is the line that we're searching for. Thanks! If you copy-paste that as an answer I'll mark it as correct  @mlainz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only vectors which are normal to (1,2,−3) and (2,1,0) are multiples of (1,2,−3)×(2,1,0)=(3,−6,−3). Take v=(1,−2,−1) and a point in the x axes (λ,0,0) such that the line (x,y,z)=sv+(λ,0,0) intersects the line k.

I'm glad it helped you. The cross product is very useful for 3D geometry problems.